# fancybox with drop-down list option pre-selected

Tags: php, fancybox

This is my fancybox initiation:

```js
$("a.appointment_button").fancybox({
 'type': 'iframe',
 'width': 400,
 'padding': 0,
 'scrolling': 'no',
 'closeBtn': true,
 'autoScale': false
});
```

I'm trying to get drop-down list option pre-selected in my fancybox for different buttons.

So for instance: when number 1 button is clicked I want option 1 of the drop-down list to be pre-selected or when number 2 button is clicked I want option 2 of the drop-down list to be pre-selected when the fancybox loads.

Could you please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really did not give any useful info, for example, what and how are you trying to display in fancybox - is it html, inline content, ajax or iframe?

If you are displaying inline content (for example, a hidden form), then you do not need to do anything related to fancybox, all changes will be "live" and your content will keep all changes after opening/closing fancybox.

If you are using iframes, then the easiest solution would be to use url parameters, for example, `appointment.php?selected_id=1`

Comment: Please see my fancybox initiation Janis!